# jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect: 0.0.0.0<00>/172.16.1.181

Tags: java, exception, smb, jcifs

I am getting an error while connecting to shared folder on remote machine.

I have configured :
Shared folder path as : //172.16.1.181/myReports

Domain Name : testLab.net

User and Password is also provided which are in same domain as 'testlab.net'

I am using JCIFS verison 1.3.17

Error is as :

```
Caused by: jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect: 0.0.0.0<00>/172.16.1.181
jcifs.util.transport.TransportException
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.readn(Transport.java:29)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.peekKey(SmbTransport.java:388)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate(SmbTransport.java:288)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.doConnect(SmbTransport.java:319)
    at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.run(Transport.java:241)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.run(Transport.java:258)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.connect(SmbTransport.java:309)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:156)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doConnect(SmbFile.java:911)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:954)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:880)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.queryPath(SmbFile.java:1335)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.exists(SmbFile.java:1417)
    at com.sv.tools.ppsfinder.svc.sharedfolder.SharedFolderReader.getFoldersList(SharedFolderReader.java:44)
    ... 4 more
```

Can anybody suggest why 'Failed to connect: 0.0.0.0<00>/172.16.1.181' may occurring ?

Update :
I can ping remote machine from my machine and I can open shared folder if I paste the same url in Win+R (Run prompt).

Comment: Is it possible that your server does not support SMB1?
JCIFS support only SMB1. What is the Server type?